# Counting days between multiple start-stop records within a calendar period

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

An activity can start and stop 0 or more times during a given time period. Each time it does either, a record is produced with the date and the action--I'll call the actions 'Activate (A)' and 'Deactivate (D)'. I need to sum up the total number of 'active' days in a given month. I'd like a simple way to do this uncluttered with exceptions and special cases. I'll have to do this in tsql.

Here's the procedural approach I've taken so far:

1. Was there a start or stop event within the period?
   a) if NO, then find the latest event that precedes the time period
      i) if that event was Start, then all days of the period are active
     ii) if the event was Stop, there are no active days in the period
    iii) done
   b) if YES...then rat's nest of procedural checks and if-thens.

As usual, I'd like to understand how others would see the problem, rather than just start down the road of coding up a routine to sort the records chronologically and loop through them.

A typical dataset:

```
6/11/2014  A
6/20/2014  D
6/24/2014  A
6/26/2014  D
6/29/2014  A
```

Here, the period of interest is June, and the first action was activate--so the activity was inactive up until 6/11. Likewise, on 6/29 things go active again, and so the remainder of the month is counted as active. Using a datediff() function on D and A dates, I get 9 + 2, and the last day of the month makes 12 total active days.

Again, just for a one-period set of data, there may be 0 or more records.

Naturally, the data could just as well look like this:

```
6/11/2014  D
6/20/2014  A
6/24/2014  D
6/26/2014  A
6/29/2014  D
```

Here, the activity was 'active' up until 6/11 when it was deactivated. Simply datediff()'ing (D - A) dates gives me an additional 4 + 3 days for a total of 17.

I'm afraid if I SELECT, SORT then DO WHILE I'm going to get wrapped around the axle. I wonder what slicker approach others might take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will give you all days for the given period with the corresponding event for the day:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b4b/7)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([dt] date, [event] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([dt], [event])
VALUES
    ('2014-06-11', 'A'),
    ('2014-06-20', 'D'),
    ('2014-06-24', 'A'),
    ('2014-06-26', 'D'),
    ('2014-06-29', 'A')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @start date, @end date
select @start = '2014-06-01', @end = '2014-06-30'
;with dates as (
  SELECT @start AS d, (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN event = 'A' THEN 'D' ELSE 'A' END FROM Table1 ORDER BY dt) AS e
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, d), COALESCE((SELECT event FROM Table1 WHERE dt = dateadd(day, 1, dates.d)), dates.e)
  FROM dates 
  WHERE dates.d < @end)
select * from dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b4b/7/0)**:

```
|          D | E |
|------------|---|
| 2014-06-01 | D |
| 2014-06-02 | D |
| 2014-06-03 | D |
| 2014-06-04 | D |
| 2014-06-05 | D |
| 2014-06-06 | D |
| 2014-06-07 | D |
| 2014-06-08 | D |
| 2014-06-09 | D |
| 2014-06-10 | D |
| 2014-06-11 | A |
| 2014-06-12 | A |
| 2014-06-13 | A |
| 2014-06-14 | A |
| 2014-06-15 | A |
| 2014-06-16 | A |
| 2014-06-17 | A |
| 2014-06-18 | A |
| 2014-06-19 | A |
| 2014-06-20 | D |
| 2014-06-21 | D |
| 2014-06-22 | D |
| 2014-06-23 | D |
| 2014-06-24 | A |
| 2014-06-25 | A |
| 2014-06-26 | D |
| 2014-06-27 | D |
| 2014-06-28 | D |
| 2014-06-29 | A |
| 2014-06-30 | A |
```

Using the query above you will be easily able to produce queries for counts, either like this:

```
declare @start date, @end date
select @start = '2014-06-01', @end = '2014-06-30'
;with dates as (
  SELECT @start AS d, (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN event = 'A' THEN 'D' ELSE 'A' END FROM Table1 ORDER BY dt) AS e
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, d), COALESCE((SELECT event FROM Table1 WHERE dt = dateadd(day, 1, dates.d)), dates.e)
  FROM dates 
  WHERE dates.d < @end)
select e, count(*) from dates GROUP BY e
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Results**:

```
| E | COLUMN_1 |
|---|----------|
| A |       13 |
| D |       17 |
```

or like this:

```
declare @start date, @end date
select @start = '2014-06-01', @end = '2014-06-30'
;with dates as (
  SELECT @start AS d, (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN event = 'A' THEN 'D' ELSE 'A' END FROM Table1 ORDER BY dt) AS e
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, d), COALESCE((SELECT event FROM Table1 WHERE dt = dateadd(day, 1, dates.d)), dates.e)
  FROM dates 
  WHERE dates.d < @end)
select 
sum(case when e='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A_days,
sum(case when e='D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as D_days
from dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Results**:

```
| A_DAYS | D_DAYS |
|--------|--------|
|     13 |     17 |
```

Comment: Is it legal to also define your table1 as a CTE after the WITH, like so: WITH table1 (d, t) AS (...), dates AS ( [your definition above] )? I've seen no reference (yet) to mixing non-recursive and recursive definitions within the same WITH scope.

Comment: did not understand your question

Comment: there you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36209 I guess you could just try yourself....

Comment: Yes--I did and it does exactly as I needed...works perfectly.

Comment: BTW, if you noticed I've made a mistake. You will need to fix it yourself (very easy to fix). If you have a event on day1 (i.e. if event for the `@start` date exists in your table) the initial `e` value in the `dates` CTE will be incorrectly set to the opposite event. Very easy to fix, by I will leave to yourself

Comment: Excellent catch. My actual data is datetime, not date, and I've found a case where the change in event doesn't seem to be caught. I've modified your SQLFiddle table to reflect the same event profile, and your code works correctly. I don't think the datatype is the issue since all of the 'actual' data I'm using has 00:00:00 for the time component anyway. The event not handled correctly by MY code is the 2014-06-26 deactivate event--very weird. Thanks again--this will definitely solve my issue.